# Trim EOL to space in UltraEdit?

Tags: notepad++, trim, ultraedit

How do you trim EOL to space in UltraEdit? In Notepad++ it's menu *Edit* → *Blank Operations* → *EOL to Space*.

1

2

3

4

After trim it's `1234`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert all, like in Notepad++, chose menu *Format* → *Convert CR/LF Wrap* (without anything selected). It can also be done on a subset of the document by first making a selection.

It is not always 100% equivalent, though. UltraEdit will not do it for empty lines, and thus it works more like applying it to independent paragraphs, whereas in Notepad++ the end result is *one* line. Without any empty lines the result is exactly the same.

This was tried with UltraEdit v. 16.2 and Notepad++ 6.9.2.